# Python what I scrape from python is not same as chorme browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I did review the examples available already here but they didn't help and thought I would ask again

When accessed this URL: https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SalesSearch?countyId=2
this provides with a list of properties in a table and one of the column in the table is a hyperlink as Details and when click on one, it shows another table and has a column named as "Approx. Upset*:"

My goal is to access each and every column data from the "Details" URL in the resulted HTML of provided URL and prepare a CSV file out of it

Code I tried is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode (without opening a window)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

url = "https://salesweb.civilview.com/Sales/SaleDetails?PropertyId=1171700135"

driver.get(url)

table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "table-striped")))

html_content = driver.page_source
print("HTML is", html_content)

driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

row = soup.find('tr', string='Approx. Upset*:')

value = row.find_next('td').get_text(strip=True)

print("Approx. Upset:", value)
```

But with this the returned HTML is not same as what I see in the browser. Not sure where it is wrong. Because the returned HTML doesn't have the element I am looking for it is resulting in error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_next'
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.page_source` only fetches the HTML as it was delivered.  The whole point of using Selenium is so you can run the Javascript to see dynamic content.  For that, you need to use Selenium APIs to access the DOM.  You will not use BeautifulSoup for this.